# How can i start two threads by changing line of "credentials.txt" file for each thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'll explain what I should do. I should create 2 threads on selenium python where each thread takes a line from the "credentials.txt" file and adds it into the variable to be used in the thread. The first thread must consider the first line of the txt file, while the second thread must consider the second line of the txt file. In this code I created two threads open at the same time but they always write the same thing by not changing the line of the txt file. Gan you help me? A thousand thanks!

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from threading import Thread

line_count = 0

def login():
    global line_count
    with open('credentials.txt') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=':')
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Chromedriver.exe")
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.get('https://twitter.com/i/flow/login')
            time.sleep(4)
            driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text").send_keys(row[0])
            time.sleep(3)


number_of_threads = 2

threads = []

for number in range(number_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=login) 
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```